# Getting error while accessing cells of row in data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

Here, am added combo box and check box in data grid view. But when am accessing the check box or combo box it was given an error as follow;

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

My data grid view after filled data looks like below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABPtS.jpg)

and back code is,

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      DataGridViewRow roow=new DataGridViewRow();;
      int rcnt = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1;
      int ccnt = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count-1;
      for (int i = 1; i <= rcnt; i++)
      {
           DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ischecked= roow.Cells[ccnt] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;  
           if((bool)ischecked.Value==true)
           {
               for (int j = 1; j < ccnt; j++)
               {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[rcnt].Cells[ccnt].ReadOnly = true;
               }
           }
           ccnt--;
      }          
}
```

Comment: I cant understand why you want to access the datagrid rows when u just make a new DataGridViewRow and you dont assign columns to it nor assign it to your datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must beging your conter "i" and "j" in your loop with 0 not 1

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. Am getting error on                                            Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index                                                                                    for code,                                                                         DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ischecked= roow.Cells[ccnt] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

Answer (score 0):

Try this  code :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Name");
            DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Username");
            DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("tr");
            col3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean");


            col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

            table.Columns.Add(col1);
            table.Columns.Add(col2);
            table.Columns.Add(col3);


            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row[col1] = "John";
            row[col2] = "John123";
            row[col3] = true ;

            table.Rows.Add(row);


             row = table.NewRow();
            row[col1] = "John1111";
            row[col2] = "John1225";
            row[col3] = false ;

            table.Rows.Add(row);

            row = table.NewRow();
            row[col1] = "John222";
            row[col2] = "John3333";
            row[col3] = true ;

            table.Rows.Add(row);


            row = table.NewRow();
            row[col1] = "John3333";
            row[col2] = "Jogggazg";
            row[col3] = false ;

            table.Rows.Add(row);


            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow roow = new DataGridViewRow(); ;
            int rcnt = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
            int ccnt = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= rcnt; i++)
            {
                roow = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ischecked = roow.Cells[ccnt] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
                if ( (bool)ischecked.Value == true)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= ccnt; j++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[rcnt].Cells[j].ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                }

            }          
        }
```

Comment: I am getting error like, **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** to the line if((bool)ischecked.Value==true)

Comment: I create a project for you,i have edit my post how containt all code ,he work for me ,try it again and check the question as solved if he  is useful for you